# GA - filtering in some profiles work in others not

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We use measurement protocol for measurements in Google Analytics. We have a "Main profile" (view) for official measurements including some IP address and bot filters. However in this "Main profile" we see no measurement protocol (MP) hits. Other hits are visible there.

If we create a new profile without any filters, measurement protocol hits start to work. If we recreate the same filters in the new profile as in the main profile, then the MP works again.

We tried also to duplicate our main profile, but even if we remove the filters there, the MP hits are still not there.

Does somebody know what else besides filters should we analyze in order to find out what is behind this strange GA behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might encounter the same issue - we found out that in our case it is caused by the "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" checkbox in the view settings. However I am not sure how exactly this option works, maybe we send too many hits at one point of time, because we use MP hits.